# PHP use default array to keep live array structured correctly

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have an array holding some default settings for my plugin. As the plugin evolves settings maybe removed or added from version to version.

Here is an example default array:

```
$defaults = array(
                    'setting1' => 'somevalue',
                    'setting2' => 'somevalue',
                    'setting4' => 'somevalue',
                  );
```

Here is an example of live settings data that the structure needs to be updated for the new $default structure:

```
$livesettings = array(
                        'setting1' => 'foo',
                        'setting2' => 'bar',
                        'setting3' => 'foobar',
                      );
```

I'm looking for a function where I can pass both arrays and the structure of the livesettings is updated to match the $defaults.

So in this case in livesettings:

1. setting1 and setting2 isn't touched. Their values stay intact
2. setting3 is removed as no longer needed
3. setting4 is added with the default value of `somevalue`

Are their any functions in PHP that can do this in one go? If yes what is it? If no how would I achieve this with PHP code?

Comment: you basically want to merge the 2 arrays. try adding a cache mechanism, as i dont think they change that often

Comment: Your question is confusing, I was expecting $livesettings to be the actual dataset you are building because you add setting 4, but then  why is setting 3 removed?

Comment: Image a plugin in use. The admin of the plugin sets the settings for this plugin stored in $livesettings. I publish a new plugin version that no longer uses/needs setting3 but now has setting4. I need to update the users settings to match this new structure without resetting the uses original settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want a combination of [array_intersect_key()](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) and [array_merge()](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

```
$livesettings = array_intersect_key($livesettings, $defaults);
$livesettings = array_merge($defaults, $livesettings);
```

The first function will remove all keys not found in `$defaults`, while the second would add items from `$defaults` not found in `$livesettings`

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to a function for this problam, you can also use the $defaults like a base array,

```
    $defaults = array(
                        'setting1' => 'somevalue',
                        'setting2' => 'somevalue',
                        'setting4' => 'somevalue',
                      );

    $livesettings = $defaults; // it will be copited by value,

    $livesettings['setting1']  = 'overriden setting 1';
    $livesettings['setting3'] = 'added new setting to live config';
```

Comment: I dont want $livesettings values overridden by $defaults values. I just want the key structure mapped from defaults to $livesettings

Comment: overriden is only for  $livesettings array, $default will not be changed.

Comment: Sorry you are completely missing the point. Understood as my question I feel could be a bit more clearer.